# Telnet into a device using an Android app

Tags: android, telnet

I want to telnet into my server using an android app.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("telnet " + ip_address.toString() + " " + Integer.parseInt(port_number.toString()));
```

I get this on my Logcat window:

```
java.io.IOException: Permission Denied
at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec()
```

Any hints or ideas?

Comment: i hope you dont have a rooted phone and you can try socket programing instead

Comment: What happens when you invoke telnet from shell?

Comment: @dtmilano: It works fro shell, as it should. Its just some problem within the app that I cannot find!

Comment: @droidhot: I am trying on emulator now, but I will not have a rooted phone.

Comment: @droidhot: Any links to do scoket programming using Android app and connect to a telnet server?

Comment: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/  try this its an eg for socket programing you will have to code it so it can connect to telnet port(port 23 i hope) etc on your on

Comment: @droidhot: Thanks, will go through it and update soon.

Comment: @droidhot: Your suggestion worked.. :) However, I cannot accept it as an answer.. There isnt an opetion to accept comments as answers.